# Как вывести слово как ссылку из TextFields в шаблон Django

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

Как вывести слово как ссылку из TextFields в шаблон Django?Я не смог разобраться как добавить атрибуты в выводимый текст в шаблоне, в интернете особо нет ответов

Answer (score 1):

В views.py передать это слово в контекст. Допустим что класс формы у Вас называется Word:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Word(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            context = {
                txt: form.cleaned_data[txt]
            }
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html', {
                'form': form
            })
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
       'form': Word()
    })
```

В шаблоне index.html мы получим доступ к переменной txt и тогда пишем код для ссылки:

```
<a href="https://google.com">{{ txt }}</a>
```